# Cross Section - Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If you have Mathematica and input:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Sin[v], Sin[u + v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi]
```

You will generate a 3D solid that looks like a cube with crushed in sides. What I want to do is take cross sections of this solid with the horizontal planes: `z = 0`, `z = 1`, `z= -1`, `z= 1/2`, and `z= -1/2`.

What is the command to generate plots of these cross sections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by specifying a `RegionFunction`, which is a boolean condition that determines where the surface is allowed to be plotted. Here, you would use

```
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < a]
```

where `a` is the height at which you want the intersecting plane to be. To illustrate this, I'll make a movie:

```
t = Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Sin[v], Sin[u + v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 
    2 Pi}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < a], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
 {a, 1, -1, -.1}
]
```

And now I'll export it as a `GIF` animation to include below:

```
Export["section.gif", Join[t, Rest[Reverse[t]]]]
```

[image: Sections]

Answer (score 3):

To just get the intersection curves you could use the `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` options, e.g.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Sin[v], Sin[u + v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {Range[-1, 1, 1/2]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]